# Do blood clots or dried wounds prevent ghusl?

Tags: ghusl

Recently, I don't remember getting hurt, but I find blood clots or dried wounds when I going to do ghusl and I'm asking if it they prevent the ghusl.

Answer (score 1):

There's the following hadith which describes vaginal bleeding:

> If it is menstrual blood then it is blood that is black and recognizable, so stop praying, and if it is other than that then perform Wudu', for it is just a vein.
>   <sub>[Sunan an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/urn/1002170) [grade: sahih]</sub>

Judging from this, ghusl would not be required because of bleeding.  In fact, [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/45666) express an opinion that wudu is not invalidated:

> ... the most likely view is that it is pure, because there is no evidence to support the view that it is impure.

[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83169) has a similar opinion:

> Anyway, the preponderant opinion of the Muslim scholars is that bleeding from an unusual place does not abort Wudu even if the amount of blood is large.